# Yii2 - get data from innerJoinWith

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models like this,
**Pipe -> outGoingPipe**

This is the active record :

```
$model= Pipe::find()
        ->select(["
                    *,
                    sum(piece) as pieces,
                    sum(bundle) as bundles
                "])
        ->innerJoinWith('outgoingPipe',false)
        ->groupBy(['bundle_group'])
        ->where(['in', 'outgoing_pipe_id', $selectedPipe])
        ->orderBy(['container' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

Now, if I check by `print_r($model)`,

I cannot see the column that came from outgoingPipe.

All the item from Pipe is success selected.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

`outgoingPipe` is available through relation:

```
$model->outgoingPipe
```

Notice that by setting second argument in `innerJoinWith()` to `false` you lazy-load this relation - it is available only after `$model->outgoingPipe` has been called.

Comment: I still get null

Comment: Show me how your `outgoingPipe` relation is defined and how you check this property.